# How to swap dots to commas in Python?

Tags: python, excel

I have an output that is written in an excel file. My values are float and in python the float point is in dot (1/3 = 0.33), but in excel float points are in commas (0,33). How can I convert all the dots to commas........................................?

```
import math

print("\nThis program calculates the maximum height and speed of a one stage rocket \n")

Isp = float(input("Write Specific Impulse in seconds = "))
min = float(input("Write the initial mass of the rocket ="))
mfuel = float(input("Write tha mass of fuel = "))
mf = float(input("Write the final mass of the rocket = "))
tb = float(input("Write the time that rockets fuel ends = "))

file = open("Ask_2_AET.csv", "w")

file.write("h in meters")
file.write(";")
file.write("V in m/s")
file.write(";")
file.write("t in seconds\n") 

g = 9.81
t = 0.000001
Ve = g * Isp

while t == tb or t < tb:

    mt = min - mfuel * (t/tb)
    y = g * (-t * Isp * (math.log(min/mt) / ((min/mt) - 1)) + t * Isp - 1/2 * t ** 2)
    V = Ve * math.log(min / mt) - g * t

    t = round(t)
    file.write(str(round(y, 2)))
    file.write(";")
    file.write(str(round(V, 2)))
    file.write(";")
    file.write(str(round(t)))
    file.write("\n")
    t += 1

Vb = V

while V > 0:

    V = Vb - g * t
    h = Vb * t - 1 / 2 * g * t ** 2

    if V > 0:

        file.write(str(round(h, 2)))
        file.write(";")
        file.write(str(round(V, 2)))
        file.write(";")
        file.write(str(round(t)))
        file.write("\n")
        t += 1
    else:
        break
```

Comment: Could you turn the float into.a string and then replace the points with a comma? : `num = str(num).replace('.', ',')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use the `replace()` method for `strings` in python. Just before writing you can convert the number to string and use the `replace()` method to replace the dot into comma:

```
num = 3.16

num = str(num).replace(".", ",")
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use

```
variable.replace(".",",")
```

If they are not strings you might need to do str() first.

Comment: Will the `.replace` work on a number? Your answer would be enhanced with a full, working line of code.

Answer (score 0):

is a csv you're reading ?
if yes, you should consider the csv module which will allows you to parse your file easily.
Then, you can convert all your str to float by using .replace() like this:

my.csv:
1,90;1,90;1,90
2,91;2,92;2,93
3,92;3,92;3,93

```
>>> import csv
>>> with open('my.csv') as f:
...  for line in f.readlines():
...   line.replace(',' , '.')
...
'1.90;1.90;1.90\n'
'2.91;2.92;2.93\n'
'3.92;3.92;3.93\n'
```